# In MySQL, can I use procedural SQL outside a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

In Sybase ASE and Microsoft SQL Server, you can use procedural SQL (control flow statements like IF/ELSE and WHILE, declaring and setting lexical variables, and so on) in [one-off SQL statement batches](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189626%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), like so:

```
-- from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182587.aspx
DECLARE @Number INTEGER;
SET @Number = 50;
IF @Number > 100
  SELECT 'The number is large.' AS large;
ELSE 
BEGIN
  IF @Number < 10
    SELECT 'The number is small.' AS small;
  ELSE
    SELECT 'The number is medium.' AS medium;
END;
```

You can send this code directly to SQL Server, without preparing it or putting it in a stored procedure, and SQL Server will send back a table with a single tuple and column, with the value "The number is medium."

From what I can tell, in MySQL, procedural SQL code is restricted to appearing only within stored procedure definitions (`CREATE PROCEDURE` or `CREATE FUNCTION` statements):

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> if 32 = 32 then
    ->   select 'yes';
    -> else
    ->   select 'no';
    -> end if;
    -> //
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
for the right syntax to use near
'if 32 = 32 then
  select 'yes';
else
  select 'no';
end if'
at line 1
```

Is this impression correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct. Lots of constructs are only valid inside stored functions, like if. It even says so in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/if.html).

```
"The IF statement for stored programs implements a basic conditional construct."
```

However, the same result can be achieved using another approach, with the [function if](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

```
select if(32 = 32, 'yes', 'no');
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c116d/2)